# Need to store a text file of words into a char array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, char

So suppose you have a a text file, and it contains 10 random words. My instructions are to get those words and store it into a char array. I know you can do this with something like 'char example[2][10] = {'word1', 'word2'}, but thats only if you know the words in particular. How could I apply this in a loop to add all the words? We can assume that we know how many words there are, and word lengths. I am using fstream to read from the file.

Comment: "_We can assume that we know how many words there are, and word lengths_" If you know this, what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: How can I append words to this char array as I go along. An example would be if I give you a closed off box, and tell you that there are 10 names and the names arent longer than 20 letter long. I know that information, but how can I append those names into my char variable as I read them from my file? Like I said in my post, I know I can append full words once I initiate the variable but how can I do it once I have already initiated the variable?

Comment: `for` loop combined with `std::ifstream::getline` (or `std::ifstream::read`, depending on requirements)?

Answer (score 1):

To do this, you must keep the number of words read so far. The index starts at `0`

```
std::ifstream f("/path/to/file.txt");
int i = 0;
char words[10][20];
std::string word;
// read the words in a loop
while (f >> word) {
    // copy the word to char array
    word.copy(words[i], sizeof(words[i]);
    ++i;
}
```

---

Although, in C++ you'd rather use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and `push_back` or `emplace_back`

```
std::ifstream f("/path/to/file.txt");
std::vector<std::string> words;
std::string word;
// read the words in a loop
while (f >> word) {
    // append the word to vector
    words.push_back(word);
}
```